# What is wrong with hiding/displaying components instead of using a navigation library?

Tags: react-native

At the moment, I have a parent element that, rather than using a navigation library to open a different screen, it uses state to track what to display and what components to hide:

```
this.state = { 
        serviceSelect : true,
        addOnShow: false,
        calendarShow: false,
}
```

I would then have a function that is passed down to the child components as "OnClick" events that alter the parent's state:

```
display(screen){
    switch(screen){
        case 'addon':
            this.setState({addOnShow: true, calendarShow: false})
        break;

        case 'calendar':
            this.setState({addOnShow: false, calendarShow: true})
        break;

        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

What are all the disadvantages with using this method that you can think of?

Comment: There is no wrong doing if firs your project, the problem is you are reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong over here. It's good if you want to have more control over your components.

Try avoiding that because these things take time. If you want to have everything custom and want to have a complete control then you can use this. I can see the code is good and might serve you the needs you have.